# How can I configure sublime to always use 4 spaces?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I know that sublime has the following space-related settings:

### Preferences.sublime-settings

```
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "use_tab_stops": false
}
```

I think this means:

- `tab_size`: When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get 4 spaces (or a tab length of 4, depending on wheather it makes tabs or spaces)
- `translate_tabs_to_spaces`: When I save a document it will translate tabs to spaces
- `use_tab_stops`: (only relevant for spaces) Sublime will not simply enter 4 spaces, but will eventually add less spaces to get to the next tab position.

But although I have this configuration, I see all the time:

[image]

My `project.sublime-project` has:

```
...
"settings":
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "use_tab_stops": true
}
...
```

How can I tell sublime to always use 4 spaces? (except for Makefiles, where it has to use tabs. But the focus of thes question is on 4, not on spaces)

I have `Linux Mint 16 Petra` and `Sublime Text build 3059`

Comment: Is this in your Preferences.sublime-settings — User or Preferences.sublime-settings — Default? If Default, is your User preferences file perhaps overriding it?

Comment: Its in my user preferences. I never touch the Default one.

Comment: I see from your screenshot that your syntax highlighting is HTML (Twig). Was this syntax option provided by a third-party plugin? Is it possible that plugin has its own override setting for indentation?

Comment: @gfullam I think the plugin was [`Twig`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Twig). As far as I can see this does not override the spaces setting. And I also have this problem with other highligting modes (LaTeX and Python, if I remember correctly)

Comment: I installed Twig and modified my User prefs and Project prefs to match yours and was not able to reproduce the problem. I am using Sublime Text 2, however, and I see you tagged the question as "sublimetext3". Perhaps it is a legitimate bug?

Comment: @gfullam: I've added it here: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/444741-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have stated is happening because your current file has indentation of 2 spaces and ST is using the auto detected indention as it has the highest priority in all Preferences<sup>[1](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/settings.html#order-of-precedence-of-sublime-settings-files)</sup>.
Add below line to Preferences
`"detect_indentation": false`
So that it won't change the indentation setting automatically.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick (sorry that it took me a while to accept your answer).